# Using react.js via npm and ASP.NET Web API in dev

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, npm

I'm writing a React.js front-end which makes calls to an ASP.NET Web API backend. For cross-site-scripting reasons I need both front and back end hosted on the same domain.

Normally this is fine, but when I'm developing my react.js site, I'm running it via the node/npm command line which runs the front-end on http://localhost:3000.

But my back-end Web API needs to be fired up as well, in this case it runs within IIS on http://localhost:5000.

So in development at least, I can't run them as the same domain, as react.js runs within the command line runner, which recompiles the app each time it changes. Of course when I run in prod, I know I can build it into a prod-ready format. But for development I was the compile-on-the-fly features to pick up immediate changes.

How can I get around this? (and I don't think the answer is to disabled cross-site-scripting or use CORS).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that within WebPack it has the ability to proxy outbound HTTP requests from the javascript, so the javascript calls the same domain and Webpack just redirects the request to your Web API.

To enable the Webpack proxy make this change to the **package.json** file in the root of your react.js app folder.

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
       ...
    "proxy":  "http://localhost:1000" //Add this line
}
```